# merge two dataframes on similar groups

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that include similar groups, example:

```
dataframe1:        
    group  Rank_real              
    1         2
    1         1
    1         3
    2         2
    2         1

dataframe2:        
    group  Rank_predicted
    2         1
    2         2
    1         1
    1         2
    1         3
```

I want to merge these two dataframes on the column group where the end result looks like this:

```
Result:
 group     Rank_real     Rank_predicted         
        1         2          1
        1         1          2
        1         3          3
        2         2          1
        2         1          2
```

I tried to do this with

```
pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, on='group')
```

However, I get:

```
Result:
     group     Rank_real     Rank_predicted         
            1         2          1
            1         2          2
            1         2          3
            1         1          1
            1         1          2
            1         1          3
            1         3          1
            1         3          2
            1         3          3
            2         2          1
            2         2          2
            2         1          1
            2         1          2
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `groupby` with `cumcount` add the additional `merge` key

```
out = df1.assign(key=df1.groupby('group').cumcount()).\
         merge(df2.assign(key=df2.groupby('group').cumcount()),on=['group','key'])
Out[68]: 
   group  Rank_real  key  Rank_predicted
0      1          2    0               1
1      1          1    1               2
2      1          3    2               3
3      2          2    0               1
4      2          1    1               2
```